# UWP MediaElement can not play after have closed

Tags: c#, uwp

Firstly, I play `MyMediaElement`, and `CurrentState` as the following (opening -> paused -> playing)

Secondly, I stop `MyMediaElementby MyMediaElement.Source = null` code. CurrentState is (closed). At this step, MediaEnded() event does not occur. (my expect is `MyMediaElemen`t becomes black if stop button is pressed)

Thirdly, I play again `MyMediaElement`, but `CurrentState`  is `(opening -> closed)`. And MyMediaElement still shows black screen. At this step, I debug at

`MediaOpened() event never comes, but MyediaElement_MediaFailed() event occurs with the message "MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED : HRESULT - 0xC00D3E85" (The media resource is not supported.`)`

In the third step, how to play MediaElement again like the first step?
_mediaStreamSource is still having a valid value, but why step 1 is OK, step 3 is failed?
My source code as bellow

```
private MediaStreamSource _mediaStreamSource;
private DispatcherTimer _mediaPlayerTimer;
...
...
private void btn_play(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Closed)
    {
        MyMediaElement.SetMediaStreamSource(_mediaStreamSource);
    }
    else
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}

private void btn_stop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyMediaElement.Stop();
    MyMediaElement.Source = null;
}

private void MyMediaElement_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MediaElement player = sender as MediaElement;
    if (player.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
    {
        _mediaPlayerTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _mediaPlayerTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        _mediaPlayerTimer.Tick += MediaPlayerTimer_Tick;
        _mediaPlayerTimer.Start();
    }
}

private void MyediaElement_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string msg = e.ErrorMessage;
}
```

Comment: `MediaEnded` Occurs when the MediaElement finishes playing audio or video. `MyMediaElement.Stop()` will not trigger `MediaEnded`. I can't reproduce your behavior yet, could you please share more information about `_mediaStreamSource`?

Comment: Hi Junjie Zhu, _mediaStreamSource is being created as the following example.    
      https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/MediaEditing/cs/Scenario2_AppendClips.xaml.cs       
   method AppendVideos_Click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem, this is an unexpected behavior that is not covered in the [MediaStreamSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.mediastreamsource?view=winrt-22621#remarks) documentation for multiplexing.

In my test, if I use `MediaClip` and `MediaComposition` to dynamically generate `MediaStreamSource` in `play_Click` like method `AppendVideos_Click`, there is no error. I will check this behavior with team. According to your scenario, it is recommended that you use the same method as in `AppendVideos_Click` to dynamically generate `MediaStreamSource`. Or use `Visibility` to achieve a similar effect.

```
private void play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Stopped)
    {
        MyMediaElement.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}

private void stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyMediaElement.Stop();
    MyMediaElement.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: Hi Junjie Zhu, Thank for your suggestion. it will take some time if do again "dynamically generate MediaStreamSource like method AppendVideos_Click" in play_Click, so I will not choose this way. If can not set source, I think stop and Collapse MyMediaElement is a solution.

Comment: Hi Junjie Zhu, I have the same issue, when I remove (myGrid.Childrent.Remove(myMedia) ) MediaElement out of a grid, then add it again. After remove line, current state of MediaElement is changed to closed. Then, I can not play again. For this issue, I can not move myMedia to other grid. Could you help me test this?

Comment: Btw, current state is closed if I use MediaStreamSource. If I use myMedia.Source = new System.Uri("ms-appx..."), it will not be closed, and can play again.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little busy lately, I'll check for you later.

Comment: Yes, waiting for you  :3 !!

Comment: You can ask a new question on StackOverflow and provide more code information so that we can further check the problem for you.